# Disable back button after logout?

Tags: php, logout

I am using php. i want redirect users to logout page when he clicks back button after login. How to achieve this? where to write the code?

i logged into site admin..logged out and then hit back button and i am able to see the previous page. Why site admin does not handle this.

This is the code for logout in site admin:

```
if( !function_exists( 'adifier_logout_inactive' ) ){
function adifier_logout_inactive( $username, $user ){
    if( !is_wp_error( $user ) ){
        $logout = true;
        if( !empty( $user->allcaps['edit_posts'] ) && $user->allcaps['edit_posts'] === true ){
            $logout = false;
        }
        else if( get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'user_active_status', true ) == 'active' ){
            $logout = false;
        }
        if( $logout === true  ){
            wp_logout();
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_login', 'adifier_logout_inactive', 10, 2 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First question: What is the `back button`?

Answer: It is a button outside the control of the web server. If presses, the browser loads again the page with the previous used URL. Some browsers (or all?) support a `back N steps button`.

What does the web server see?

The web server sees only the URL. He does't know if the URL is loaded again or if the user used one of the back buttons. So the (new) URL is the only data for the decision. The only chance to recognize the the usage of a `back button` is to use session data too.

Pitfalls: The user can open several windows. He can press the reload button. He can set and use bookmarks.

With this knowledge you should rethink how to detect thew `back button` and if you really want to mange (some aspects of) it. Or in other words: Is it rally worth to forbid loading the previous URL again.

A soluton may be: If the user enters the login page and is already logged-in, then redirect him to another page (welcome, status, overview). I do that at my websites.